# Dimension of rational subspace ($\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]^4$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For the rational space say $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ I know that this has dimension $2$ as $(1,\sqrt{2})$ forms a basis of dimension $2$. But what if you take $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]^4$? Would the dimension then be $4\times 2=8$?

Comment: Can you tell us what $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]^4$ is?

Comment: It should be a vector space over $\Bbb Q$. You're right.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes I agree with that

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net is that a vector $\mathbb{Q}^4$ with each element of the form $a+\sqrt{2}b$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of a finite [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of finite dimensional linear spaces is the sum of their dimension.

So if by $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]^4$ you mean $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \times \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \times \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\times \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, then yes its dimension as a linear space over $\mathbb Q$ is equal to $8$.